# How do I get the mean in a range of values in a 2d DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, mean

I got a 2d DataFrame (df_1) in my Jupyter-Notebook and want to copy the mean of a certain range of values into a new DataFrame. The first bin (based on v_wind) should count from 3.00 to 3.10 and avaraging all corresponding values from p_abs. The data contains about 5502 rows.

```
    p_abs          v_wind

    19.94           3.00
     3.35           3.02
    29.26           3.03
    47.97           3.04
    42.99           3.05
    16.20           3.06
    19.00           3.07
    34.54           3.10
    16.16           3.10
     7.49           3.11
    48.85           3.14
    23.19           3.16
    25.69           3.18
    34.47           3.18
    27.82           3.19
    31.18           3.19
    58.86           3.19
    36.17           3.19
    36.47           3.19
    33.79           3.22
    23.72           3.23
```

I already tried to summarise the DataFrame with:

```py
df_1.groupby(['v_wind']).mean()
```

but this does not allow me to avarage all values in my range.

Could someone tell me how to create a new DataFrame (df_2), looking like this:

```
   p_abs          v_wind

 avg_value          3.1
 avg_value          3.2
 avg_value          3.3
 avg_value          3.4
 avg_value          3.5
 avg_value          3.6
```

I am a bloody beginner in Python and thankfull for any advice...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `pd.cut`. You'll need to determine if you want bins like `[3, 3.1)` or `(3, 3.1]` by specifying `right` as an argument.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

bins = np.arange(3, 4, 0.1)
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.v_wind, bins=bins, right=False)).p_abs.mean()

v_wind
[3.0, 3.1)    25.530000
[3.1, 3.2)    31.740833
[3.2, 3.3)    28.755000
[3.3, 3.4)          NaN
[3.4, 3.5)          NaN
[3.5, 3.6)          NaN
[3.6, 3.7)          NaN
[3.7, 3.8)          NaN
[3.8, 3.9)          NaN
Name: p_abs, dtype: float64
```

---

If you want this to be more generalizable instead of hardcoding the bins you could get "even" bins with:

```
space = 0.1
bins = np.arange(df['v_wind'].min()//space*space, 
                 (df['v_wind'].max()+space)//space*space, space)
#array([3. , 3.1, 3.2, 3.3])
```

Comment: Use `df['v_win'].min()//1` or `np.floor(df['v_win'].min())` ?